# I am trying to use custom php function in twig, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I tried to use my custom php function in twig.
When I type {{current_url}} in my page.html.twig nothing happens.
I also tried {{kint(current_url)}}, it outputs NULL
This is my code

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\nextprev\plugin\block\customtwigoutput;


use Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension;
use  Drupal\nextprev\nextprevmodule\path;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

public function url() {
   $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
   return $current_path;
}


  public function getFilters() {
     return array(
       'current_url' => new \Twig_Function_Function(array('Drupal\nextprev\plugin\block\customtwigoutput\AppExtension', 'url')),
     );
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the webserver log?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add services.yml to it? This is a sample;

```
twig.url:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\AppExtension
    tags:
        - { twig.extension }
```

Comment: I did not.
I am trying to add it but I'm kinda stuck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with a twig function instead :

**In your extension** :

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('current_url', array($this, 'url')),
    );
}
```

**In your view**

```
 {{ current_url() }}
```